# Symfony Best Practices : Twig or FormType ? (label, translation...)

Tags: symfony

What are the best practices for the render of forms :
write label in formType or in twig ?

```
    ->add('title',TextType::class,[
                'label'=> 'My title',
            ])
```

VS

```
{{ form_label(form.foo, 'My title')
```

(Without forgetting that the text can be translated)

Answer (score 1):

Keeping everything on one place is the good practice. That means in the form type.

This way the reusability is better, because you don’t need to write the labels every time. The form types also support translations of the labels, so pretty much you don’t loose anything...